# How to call function from class to main?

Tags: c++, function, class, call

I need conj for complex number.

For example complex number X.

I wrote this code, but i dont know how to call it in main.

```
Kompleks operator ~() const {
    return Kompleks(Re() , -Im());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just implemented the Complement Operator of the class "Kompleks" ([documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxt4z71k.aspx)). In your main, if x is a Kompleks object, writing "~x" will yield the conjugate of x. For example :

```
Kompleks x(1, 2);
Kompleks y(0, 0);

y = ~x;
```

after this code, y will contain the conjugate of x.

Comment: But since the conjugate of a complex number cannot really be considered as its complement (can it ?), I would advice that you implement a new method of Kompleks that returns one's conjugate.

Answer (score 0):

You can call it like

```
int main() {
    Kompleks X;
    Kompleks conj = ~X;
}
```